# What are the ramifications of passing & assigning arrays as pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

As background, I gave an answer to this post a little while ago:

[Return array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/c-return-array-in-a-function/3473448#3473448)

And it unintentionally kicked off a really long comment chain about pointers vs. arrays in C++ because I tried to oversimplify and I made the statement "arrays are pointers".  Though my final answer sounds pretty decent, it was only after some heavy editing in response to a lot of the comments I got.

This question is not meant to be troll bait, I understand that a pointer and an array are not the same thing, but some of the available syntax in the C++ language certainly makes them behave very similarly in a lot of cases.  (FYI, my compiler is `i686-apple-darwin9-g++-4.0.1` on `OS X 10.5.8`)

For instance, this code compiles and runs just fine for me (I realize `x[8]` is a potential segmentation fault):

```
  //this is just a simple pointer                                                                                                                                                            
  int *x = new int;
  cout << x << " " << (*x) << " " << x[8] << endl; //might segfault                                                                                                                          

  //this is a dynamic array                                                                                                                                                                  
  int* y = new int[10];
  cout << y << " " << (*y) << " " << y[8] << endl;

  //this is a static array                                                                                                                                                                   
  int z[10];
  cout << z << " " << (*z) << " " << z[8] << endl;
```

That particular snippet makes it look like pointers and arrays can be used almost identically, but if I add this to the bottom of that code, the last two lines won't compile:

```
  x = y;
  x = z;
  y = x;
  y = z;
  //z = x; //won't compile
  //z = y; //won't compile
```

So clearly the compiler at least understands that `z` and `x` are different things, but I can interchange `x` and `y` just fine.

This is further confusing when you look at passing arrays to functions and returning arrays from functions.  Consider this example (again, I am aware of the potential segmentation faults here when passing `x`):

```
void foo(int in[])
{
  cout << in[8] << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                      
}

void bar(int* in)
{
  cout << in[8] << endl;                                                                                                                                                                     
}

int main()
{
  //this is just a simple pointer                                                                                                                                                            
  int *x = new int;
  foo(x);
  bar(x);

  //this is a dynamic array                                                                                                                                                                  
  int* y = new int[10];
  foo(y);
  bar(y);

  //this is a static array                                                                                                                                                                   
  int z[10];
  foo(z);
  bar(z);
}
```

All this code properly compiles and runs on my machine.

I feel like I have a decent internal understanding of what's going on here, but if you asked me to articulate exactly what's happening, I don't feel like I could satisfactorily explain.  So here's what I'm getting at:

- When I pass an array to a function as `int* in` instead of `int in[]`, what am I gaining or losing?  Is the same true when returning an array as `int*`? **Are there ever bad side effects from doing this?**
- If I asked you what the data type of `y` is, would you say pointer to int, array of ints or something else?
- Similarly, what happens when I say `x = y` vs. `x = z`?  I'm still able to use `x[]` and access the things that were originally in `y` or `z`, but is this really just because pointer arithmetic happens to land me in memory space that is still valid?

I've dug through all the similar array/pointer questions on SO and I'm having trouble finding the definitive explanation that clears this up for me once and for all.

Comment: `int* in` is the same as `int in[]` as a function parameter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/484900#484900

Comment: Good link.  Didn't find that one on my searches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ is statically typed, so of course the compiler understands that `x` and `z` are not the same kind of thing. They have different types - z is an array, x and y are pointers.

The reason `z = x` doesn't compile isn't (just) that the types are incompatible, though, it's that you can't assign to an array variable at all. Ever. `x = z` assigns to x, a pointer to the first element of z. `x = y` assigns the value of `y` to `x`.[*]

*When I pass an array to a function as int* in instead of int in[], what am I gaining or losing?*

They do exactly the same thing, so you have no choice to make. Possibly you have been misled by the fact that C++ syntax permits `int in[]` as a function parameter. The type of the parameter `in` is not any kind of array, it is `int*`.

*If I asked you what the data type of y is*

It's `int*`. That's what it's declared as, so that's what it is.

The *value that it holds* is a pointer to (the first element of) an array. I frequently use that formula: "pointer to (the first element of)" in cases where I'd like to say "pointer to array", but can't because there's the potential for ambiguity as to whether the type involved is pointer-to-array, or not.

However, pointers-to-arrays are rarely used in C++, because the size of the array is part of the type. There's no such type as "pointer to an array of int" in C++, just "pointer to array of 1 int", "pointer to array of 2 int", etc. This usually isn't very convenient, hence the use of a pointer to the first element of an array whose size may not be known at compile time.

*is this really just because pointer arithmetic happens to land me in memory space that is still valid*

Pretty much, yes. The size of the array is part of the type of z, but is not part of the type of x or y, and also is not part of the type of the result of z decaying to a pointer to its first element. So `y` could be a pointer to the first of 10 elements, or just to 1 element. You only know the difference by context, and by requiring of your callers that the value you have points to what it's supposed to point to.

"Happens" is leaving too much to chance, though - part of your job when using arrays is to make sure you don't stray beyond their bounds.

[*] `z = x` isn't allowed, even after you've done `x = z`, because z is (and always will be) an particular array of 10 ints in memory. Back when C was designed, there was a question of whether array variables could in principle be "reseatable", meaning that you could do:

```
int z[10];
int y[10];
z = y; // z is now an alias for y
y[0] = 3;
// z[0] now has the value 3
```

Dennis Ritchie decided not to allow this, because it would prevent him from distinguishing arrays from pointers in a way that he needed to do. So `z` cannot ever refer to a different array from the one it was declared as. Read all about it here: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html, under "Embryonic C".

Another plausible meaning for `z = y` could be `memcpy(z,y,sizeof(z))`. It wasn't given that meaning either.

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental difference between a pointer and an array is that the pointer has a unique memory address that *holds* the address of the array data.

An array name, though treated as a pointer based on context, does not itself have a memory location whose address you can take.  When it is treated as a pointer, its value is generated at runtime as the address of its first element.

That is why you can assign its value to another pointer but not vice versa.  There is no pointer memory location to treat as an l-value.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are not pointers, but ***arrays easily decay to pointers*** to their first element. Additionally, C (and thus C++) allow ***array access syntax to be used for pointers***.

> When I pass an array to a function as int* in instead of int in[], what am I gaining or losing? Is the same true when returning an array as int*? Are there ever bad side effects from doing this?

You're gaining nothing, because `int[]` is just another way to write `int*`. If you want to pass an array, you have to pass it per *reference*, exactly matching its size. Non-type template arguments can ease the problem with the exact size:

```
template< std:::size_t N >
void f(int (&arr)[N])
{
   ...
}
```

> If I asked you what the data type of y is, would you say pointer to int, array of ints or something else?

It's a pointer to the first element of a dynamically allocated array.

> Similarly, what happens when I say x = y vs. x = z?

You assign the addresses of different objects of different types to the same pointer. (And you leak an `int` on the heap. `:)`)

> I'm still able to use x[] and access the things that were originally in y or z, but is this really just because pointer arithmetic happens to land me in memory space that is still valid?

Yep. As I said, pointers conveniently and confusingly allow array syntax to be applied to them. However, that still doesn't make a pointer an array.

Comment: I'd be very interested in why this was down-voted? What's wrong with it?

Comment: it looks like some poor misinformed induhvidual blew through and downvoted several factually correct answers in this set.

Comment: @Amardeep: Haha, "a poor, misinformed individual" is a nice way to say "asshole". `:)`

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers.  It was somewhat of a coin flip between you and @SteveJessop.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brent: I think Steve's is a pretty good answer, so it's fine the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an snippet from [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&dq=expert+c+programming&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=4SdsTJz6C4H48Abf4YjBCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false) (and C++ semantics follows from its backward compatibility with C). Array "are" pointers in the following cases:

1. An array name **in an expression** (in contrast with a declaration) is treated by the compiler as a pointer to the first element of the array (this does not apply to `sizeof`) (ANSI C Standard, 6.2.2.1)
2. A subscript is always equivalent to an offset from a pointer (6.3.2.1)
3. An array name **in the declaration of a function parameter** is treated by the compiler as a pointer to the first element of the array (6.7.1)

This basically means that:

```
int arr[20]; int* p = arr;
```

is equivalent to:

```
int arr[20]; int* p = &arr[0];
```

Then

```
int arr[20]; int x = arr[10];
```

is equivalent to:

```
int arr[20]; int x = *( arr + 10 );
```

And

```
void func( int arr[] );
```

is equivalent to:

```
void func( int* arr );
```

On the other hand, pointers are never transformed back into arrays - that's why your last two lines do not compile.

Comment: +1 for citing van der Linden's book, it's a must-read for experience C programmers.

Answer (score 1):

> When I pass an array to a function as
>   int* in instead of int in[], what am I
>   gaining or losing? Is the same true
>   when returning an array as int*? Are
>   there ever bad side effects from doing
>   this?

AFAIK, one is just syntactic sugar for the other and they mean exactly the same.

The version with `[]` probably just gives a strong hint that this function expects a pointer into an array, not a pointer to a single object.

You will notice a difference when it comes to real multi-dimensional arrays vs array of pointers (to arrays), because in such case only the first dimension decays to a pointer with multi-dimensional arrays. Those things have a completely different layout in memory (one big contiguous block vs one small block of pointers to distinct blocks of memory).

> If I asked you what the data type of y
>   is, would you say pointer to int,
>   array of ints or something else?

The type of y is a pointer to int. In fact, in case of a dynamically allocated array, you never get to see the array at all! That is, there is no way to determine the size of the allocation with sizeof, unlike actual arrays.

> Similarly, what happens when I say x =
>   y vs. x = z? I'm still able to use x[]
>   and access the things that were
>   originally in y or z, but is this
>   really just because pointer arithmetic
>   happens to land me in memory space
>   that is still valid?

This is because x is a pointer. You will not be able to do `z = x;` because you can't assign to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's no difference (at all) between a function parameter like `int *in` and `int in[]`. For a function parameter, these are just different ways of spelling `pointer to T`. The only way they can differ at all is (possibly) something like readability (e.g., if you intend to always pass the base address of an array, you might find array notation more fitting, whereas if you intend to pass the address of a single object, you might find pointer notation more tasteful).
2. In the code above, `y` clearly has the type `pointer to int`.
3. `x` and `y` are pointers, which can be assigned. `z` is an array, which cannot be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside (which has some relevance to the topic - would have added this as a comment but don't have enough rep.) - you can gauge the number of elements in an array vs. using a pointer. Or stated differently sizeof returns sizeof(array_type)*num_elements_in_array vs returning the size of the pointer. Glib provides [this macro](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.15/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#G-N-ELEMENTS:CAPS) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> When I pass an array to a function as int* in instead of int in[], what am I gaining or losing? Is the same true when returning an array as int*? Are there ever bad side effects from doing this?

Your not gaining or losing anything

> If I asked you what the data type of y is, would you say pointer to int, array of ints or something else?

I would call y a pointer to an array of ints

> Similarly, what happens when I say x = y vs. x = z? I'm still able to use x[] and access the things that were originally in y or z, but is this really just because pointer arithmetic happens to land me in memory space that is still valid?

`x = y` does **not** make a copy of the array pointed to by y only a copy of the pointer in y.

`x = z` does **not** make a copy of the array z, only a pointer to the value of the first element.

Also, **free allocated memory**.

Comment: If you call y a pointer to an array of ints, what would `int (*ptr)[contant];` be?

Comment: It would be the same. I call `y` that because it points to an allocated array of ints.