# How do you make a function "size-aware" of its parameters?

Tags: c++

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473454/499125

```
int ( &fillarr( int (&arr)[5] ) )[5] { // no decay; argument must be size 5
    return arr;
}
```

The definition above can force the compiler to become size-aware of its parameters. This statement seems complex to me. Can someone give an anatomy of this statement or explain how does the statement achieves the size-awareness?

Can this be extended to handle multiple parameters?

Comment: That function *returns* a reference to an `int[5]`, which doesn't seem to be what you need or want.

Comment: fillar is a function taking one parameter of type reference to an array of five `int`s, returning a reference to an array of five `int`s.

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: It can be extended: `int ( &fillarr( int (&arr1)[5], int (&arr2)[5] ) )[5] { }` But please, use vectors or `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all boils down to being able to read the declaration. A simpler way of writing exactly the same would be:

```
typedef int int5[5]; // create a typedef
int5& fillarr( int5& ) {
}
```

As of the exact way of reading the original declaration, just break it into pieces:

```
int (&fillarr( int (&arr)[5] ))[ 5 ];
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^           // A: reference to array of 5 int
^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^   // B: reference to array of 5 int
      ^^^^^^^^               ^         // C: function taking A and returning B
```

Comment: wait, what's that [5] doing _behind_ int5? Does this turn all `int5` into `int _sth_ [5]`? Such as `int5 &` -> `int & [5]` ?

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent: This is the *joy* of C style type declarations. In the same way that `int arr[5];` declares an *array of 5 int*, `typedef int int5[5];` creates a type alias that represents an *array of 5 int*. What is `[5]` doing *behind* the name? That is how declarations go in the language.

Answer (score 2):

You can split understanding this in two parts, 1) the return value and 2) the parameter type:

```
int ( &fillarr() )[5] {
  static int arr[5];
  return arr;
}
```

We can have a look at the type: `int (&fillarr())[5]`. To understand this, unfortunately the old C rule: "Declaration is like usage in expressions" doesn't work with references, so let's have a look at a similar declaration instead:

```
int (*fillarr())[5];
```

This is a function that returns a *pointer* instead of a *reference* to an array of size 5. How do I figure? Well, assume we do have a function `f` that returns a pointer to an array of ints, how would we access the fifth element? Let's see, we first have to call the function: `f()`. Then we have to dereference the result `*f()` and then access the fifth element (which doesn't exist, but ignore that) `(*f())[5]` which is an `int`. This is exactly the declaration syntax:

```
int x;
int (*f())[5];
x = (*f())[5];
//    ^^^-------- call f -> yields pointer to array of 5 ints
//   ^----------- dereferene the result of f -> yields array of 5 ints
//        ^^^---- access the fifth element
```

Now you only substitute the `*` for an `&` because you're returning a reference in your example.

The parameter syntax works analogously.