# Convert std::string to const char* for printf Consumption

Tags: c++, string, c++11, printing, printf

Let us consider the below code example. Basically, `getMessage1` (internally) creates an `std::string` which is meant to be returned and then printed via `printf`. How do I convert/cast/manipulate variable `myString` so that the output looks like the one from `getMessage2`?

I am aware that `getMessage3` works, but it requires me to include `.c_str()` in every `printf` statement (and I'd like to avoid this extra *suffix*).

```
#include <string>

const char* getMessage1() {
    std::string myString = "SomeOutput";
    return myString.c_str();
}

const char* getMessage2() {
    return "SomeOutput"; 
}

std::string getMessage3() {
    std::string myString = "SomeOutput";
    return myString;
}

int main() {
    printf("#1: %s \n", getMessage1());         // prints #1: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠¿ⁿ9"w
    printf("#2: %s \n", getMessage2());         // prints #2: SomeOutput
    printf("#3: %s \n", getMessage3().c_str()); // prints #3: SomeOutput

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might I ask why you do not go with `cout`?

Comment: `getMessage1` has undefined behavior, you're returning a pointer to the string's data but it won't survive when the function ends.

Comment: @Aziuth Because I usually do sth like `%19s` to align the outputs. If that's possible with `cout` I am happy to change it.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX [Something like this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f595191aa0fadbd)

Comment: @Borgleader Ah, nice. Is there a general aversion of `printf` versus `cout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with getMessage1 is that you return pointer to local variable which is deleted as soon as you leave this function giving you dangling pointer.

The simplest solution would be to make myString static if possible so its lifetime will be as long as the program itself.

```
const char* getMessage1() {
    static std::string myString = "SomeOutput";
    return myString.c_str();
}

int main() {
    printf("#1: %s \n", getMessage1());         // prints #1: SomeOutput
    return 0;
}
```

[Link to working example on ideone](https://ideone.com/K6k7Pw)

For some more examples see [how to return pointer of local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042552/returning-a-pointer-of-a-local-variable-c).