# The lifetime of a pointer reference in C++

Tags: c++, memory

I wrote some code that involves moving and changing variables in C++. Below is what I have wrote.

```
#include <iostream>

void six(int*& ptr) {
    int s = 6;
    ptr = &s;
}

int main() {
    int f = 5;
    int* ptr = &f;

    std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
    six(ptr);

    if (ptr) {
        std::cout << *ptr;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "null\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

so this prints:

```
5
6
```

I tried another code, adding a single line:

```
#include <iostream>

void six(int*& ptr) {
    int s = 6;
    ptr = &s;
    free(&s); // added line
}

int main() {
    int f = 5;
    int* ptr = &f;

    std::cout << *ptr << '\n';
    six(ptr);

    if (ptr) {
        std::cout << *ptr;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "null\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this gives an error after printing `5` because what the modified pointer is pointing is not available when called the second time.

However, I am confused at the first case. When calling `six` in the main function, variable `s` is not in the main scope, but the value itself still continues to remain in the memory to be referenced. Doesn't C++ automatically destroy variables and clean them when it goes out of the scope? Is this a memory leak?

Comment: First code doesn't always act like that. It is undefined behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042552/returning-a-pointer-of-a-local-variable-c. Also You can't free automatic variable. `free(&s);` is nonsence.

Comment: @openingnow Thanks for the comment, but I am not talking about whether the code is right or not. Both had no problems with compiling.

Comment: It *does* compiles, but causes error.

Comment: @openingnow Yes, and I already wrote that it produced an error. What I am curious about is the behavior from the first case.

Comment: It *can* have six in memory which is not guaranteed. If you run first code at https://www.onlinegdb.com/ with `-O3` flag, value is changed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable

Comment: @openingnow I tried my code in VS2019. Also tried it in onlinegdb.com, too. Maybe this is a problem with a compiler?

Comment: No, it's just an undefined behavior. C++ spec doesn't clarify whether destroyed value is actually removed from memory.

Comment: @openingnow Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case is not a memory leak, but an ***undefined behaviour*** because your variable go out of scope.

In this case you don't know when the memory will be cleaned(replaced) o reallocated.

So in some case the result can be correct but it's a pure question of luck.