# Why my I can't return an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm trying to return a pointer to an array from a function but I have an issue. When I try to output like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* Somma_Array(int[],int[],int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int A[n],B[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>A[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>B[i];
    int *c=Somma_Array(A,B,n);
    for(int i=0;i<n*2;i++)cout<<c[i];
}

int* Somma_Array(int v[],int p[],int size)
{
    int r[size*2];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)r[i]=v[i];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)r[i+size]=p[i];
    return r;
}
```

it prints weird numbers instead of the actual number. I tried to do what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/c-return-array-in-a-function) question says but it does not work. It gives me the following warning:

```
[Warning] address of local variable 'r' returned [enabled by default]
```

I'm using bloodshed dev-c++.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: You're returning a pointer to an array that no longer exists as soon as you return.

Comment: It's going out of scope my man

Comment: Eric Lippert had an [awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/392044) for this question..

Comment: @chris - Doh!  You beat me to it..

Comment: Also know that `int A[n], B[n]` where `n` is not a compile time constant is a language *extension* supported by some compilers and is not standard.

Comment: Because `r` is locally allocated in the call stack, you cannot be passed as parameter to the caller.

Comment: That r is done (invalid) after return, and a pointer is not holding data (it is just pointing to data)

Comment: Why are you using arrays ? Use a vector

Comment: @GIJoe now I'm using them, resolved the problem with them

Answer (score 3):

You define a stack allocated array `r`, which is destroyed when you exit the function `Soma_Array`. This is one of the (many) reasons vectors are preferred to plain arrays - they handle allocation and deallocation for you.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getArray() 
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Short form: `return {1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 3):

The following:

```
int r[size*2];
```

defines `r` locally.  When the function exits (as in the scope of the function expires), `r` will be destroyed since it is bound to the function's scope.  You are likely seeing junk data from the stack frame.

you could fix this by doing the following:

```
int* r = new int[size * 2];
```

The variable `r` will now be heap allocated and exist beyond the scope of the function.

**IMPORTANT** by doing this, you now must manually free `r` when you are done with it.  So for instance, your calling code will look something like this:

```
int* result = Somma_Array(v, p, size);
/* ... do stuff ... */
delete[] result;
```

Since `r` is an array, note the use of `delete[]` instead of `delete`.  `delete[]` is the correct way to destroy arrays.

**A Better Alternative**

Would [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) be more what you are after?  This is a much safer alternative to hand-rolled arrays.  The vector is safer to use, scales automatically as you add elements, and cleans itself up nicely when it leaves scope (assuming you are using a value-type instance).  Additionally, vectors can be copied and moved out of functions easily.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return arrays in C++. Especially, you should not return a pointer to a local array. You can however return a `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> Somma_Array(int v[], int p[], int size)
{
    std::vector<int> r(2 * size);
    std::copy(v, v + size, r.begin());
    std::copy(p, p + size, r.begin() + size);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: How so? The question I linked does it, doesn't it?

Comment: @NetHacker, It returns a pointer (or an `int` depending on which declaration you're talking about). [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/997e6debe4fe3ad8) returns an array.

Comment: Ok, I'll return a vector so.

Comment: Yes and no. You can, but you can't ;-) You do return an address, not an array ("array decay"). The address points to a deceased local var, as Fred correctly pointed out. That's bad. That's why you can't. You _can_ new an array in that func and return _that_ address, and it will work.