# Is it possible to declare a function returning an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried this:

```
int ([]foo)();
int[] foo();
int (foo[])();
```

But it didn't declare what I expected. Is it possible?

I don't mean declaring a function returning a pointer. 
I need to return exactly an array.

Comment: What is the difference between a pointer and an array, for you ?

Comment: You can't return an array, but you can return a reference to an array, or a `std::array`. What do you actually need this for?

Comment: @Ninetainedo Well, it's the different type. It's not only for me, it's for all. The thing that there's the array-to-pointer conversion and arrays're adjusted to pointers when they're odr-used

Comment: I am really curious about your requirements because the array will be implicitly turned into a pointer. So what will it change, concretly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to return from your function is actually a pointer to the first element in the array:

```
int* arr(int arr[]);
```

for more information look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function) function.

Comment: You should be more explicit because of the `I don't mean declareing a function returning a pointer.` part of the question.

Comment: added a link to the answer