# Function Return Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function and want to return a 2d array:

```
int flip[5][5](int input[5][5]);
```

But it returns an error: no function error allowed (this is a translation)

How can I fix this?

This works:

```
void flip(int input[5][5]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function

Comment: Please, post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for returning an array is ugly. You're better off using a typedef, or auto.

```
auto flip(int input[5][5]) -> int[5][5];
```

However the problem you have is, you aren't passing the array to the function as a reference or pointer, which won't work.

```
typedef int myArray[5][5];

void foo(myArray& arr) {
    //do stuff
}

int main() {
    int arr[5][5];
    foo(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

As an aside, working with arrays like this is tedious, you're better off using a container from the STL.

Comment: I chose the method with typedef and it work. Thanks! Still one question: wanted to create a copy of the input argument arr in the function foo. How can I do this?

Comment: The only way to "copy" the array is to put it on the heap (via `new`). If you create a local variable and try to return it from a function, it will get destroyed as soon as the function ends, that's no good. Keep in mind, if you use `new` you must use `delete` on it after, or you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

In this function declaration

```
void flip(int input[5][5]);
```

the parameter is implicitly adjusted to pointer to the first element of the array. So actually the function declaration looks like

```
void flip(int ( *input )[5] );
```

You may not return an array because arrays do not have a copy constructor.

You may return an array by reference provided that the array itself is not a local variable of the function.

So for example if your funciotn gets an array by reference then you may return this array from the function.

For example

```
int ( & flip(int ( &input )[5][5]) )[5][5];
```

You can wrap your array in a structure and return this structure along with the array.

For example

```
struct data
{
    int a[5][5];
};

data flip( int input[5][5] );
```

Comment: A `typedef` or `using` declaration will make the syntax human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 5>` instead of a built-in array type.