# Why can't a return type be function type but function pointer in c++?

Tags: c++

```
int method1() {
    return 0;
}

decltype(method1) method2() {
    return method1;
}
```

I compile my code,get an error: ‘method2’ declared as function returning a function,
then I change the return type to function pointer,it works,I just want to why it is so.

```
decltype(method1) *method2() {
    return method1;
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted `decltype(method1())`, if you expected `method2` to return `int`. If you wanted to return the whole function, it is nonsense. You can return the address of the function, which is a function pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, functions and arrays cannot be returned. It is how the language is designed.

You have to return either pointer or reference to them. You've already tried with pointer, which works. The following, which returns reference, should also work:

```
decltype(method1)& method2() {
   return method1;  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3473454/649322
Just providing some related discussion.

Answer (score 1):

What code do you want the compiler to return when it returns a "function"?  Do you want the machine code returned?

There's no way for a compiler to do this sanely.  Besides, since you probably don't want self-modifying code, you don't really want a copy of the code.  Instead it is possible to return the address of a function.

Comment: That reason may seem plausible at first, but then why returning arrays dont work?

Comment: "*The same general principle is true of an array: you can't know how long it is*" .. that is most certainly wrong. The compiler **does** know how long an *array* is!

Comment: @Nawaz: the compiler might know in one translation unit (i.e. a file) but not in another.  It won't know across the entire function call unless there is link time optimization turned on.  But in general it can't be true (it won't work across a library call for instance).

Comment: What it has to do with TU? The size is mentioned in the type of array itself !!!  `T array[N];` is an array which takes `sizeof(T) * N` bytes. What else the compiler needs to know?

Comment: @Nawaz: but arrays decay to pointers.  You can't do `a= b` with two arrays even of the same size (you need to explicitly copy).  Same with the return type, it just doesn't make sense.  And if it does make sense then do it _explicitly_.

Comment: @dave: If they decay, they're no longer arrays. We're talking about returning "arrays", not pointers. So why is that not possible? Also, the language allows implicit decaying of arrays into pointers is because they cannot be returned otherwise, by design. Now why the language is designed in that way, is unknown to many of us. But you seem to know that, claiming that "how long an array is" cannot be known.. which is WRONG. The size of the array is known the compiler, yet it disallows it. Why exactly?

Comment: @Nawaz: perhaps, "can't be known" was too strong.  And the question doesn't talk about arrays anyway (that's a more complicated question than "why can't I return a function", because it could make sense for small arrays to be copied).  So I've removed that addition to the answer.

Comment: @dave: Now since you have removed array-part, now coming back to function. Is there anything substantial to support your view? Any quote from Design and Evolution of C++ or such?

Comment: @Nawaz: what does "return a function" even mean? I think I answer why that isn't a sane thing that you want done.

Comment: @dave: What does `method1` mean? What exactly is it? It is something that refers to something (some piece of code). But still what exactly is it?

Comment: @Nawaz: good question! I can tell you what it isn't: it isn't an rvalue.

Comment: @dave: Whatever it is, it is designed to be so. If it is not designed to be X, it cannot be X. But your answer seems to claim that there is some *inherent* problem in returning a function, which is why it is impossible to return a function. For such a tall claim, you need to support it with some quote from the designer. Because there are lots of other languages in which returning a function is not a problem; in fact some higher level features of some languages are built on this feature!

Comment: @Nawaz: A function isn't a value. A function's address is a value.  The first doesn't make sense for a function to return, the second does.  If you don't like that as an answer, then down vote, comment and move on.  But this badgering is annoying and isn't useful.  It was exactly this confusion which solved the question asked.

Comment: @dave: *"A function isn't value"*. Even if that is true, the question is, why is it not so? You just have replaced one question with another. Also, if there was some inherent problem in returning function, no languages would have supported it. But that is not true.

Comment: @Nawaz,so,what's your point about why the array and function can't be returned?

Comment: @cong: they cannot be returned because the language is not designed to support this. Now the question is, why Bjarne Stroustrup has designed the language in this way? I dont have an answer to that. For that you've to ask him, or read his *"Design and Evolution of C++"* to figure out that. I've searched through the index (and few pages) of this book, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Function pointers can most certainly be returned.  They are just a pointer and you can implement call back functions that way.