# Why does this for-loop in my function will only run once, even when it's supposed to run multiple times?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, c++11, for-loop

Could someone explain to me why this for-loop only runs one time no matter what     n is:

```
double CalcDist(unsigned int n, Point p, Point* s)
{
    double sd[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sd[i] = s[i].Dist_To(p);
        return sd[i];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `double sd[n];` is not allowed in C++ when `n` is not a compile time constant. You seem to be using a gcc extension.

Comment: What did you expect would happen?

Comment: n is declared at runtime, then passed into this function. I expected the loop to run as many times as n

Comment: `return sd[i];` will cause not only breaking the loop but returns the functions to the calling thread.

Comment: @Raindrop7 how would I return the values into an array?

Comment: @xtrap: what values?

Comment: @xtrap http://stackoverflow.com/q/3473438/327083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to determine the distance between one point to each point in an array, it goes like this :

```
double * CalcDist(unsigned int n, Point p, Point* pointsArray) {
    double * result = new double[n]; //Iso C++ forbids veriable length array
                                     //so don't use result[i] but this instead
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //set i as an unsigned int as n is one
        result[i] = pointsArray[i].Dist_To(p);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now, how do I access that array outside of this function? Let's say I want to sort the array elsewhere.

Comment: The return gives you the adress of the array so you can access it when you catch the return : 
double * foo = CalcDist(8, p, array);
//do something with foo
Don't forget to delete it after with delete[] result;

Comment: To be really safe, you should also use a shared_ptr so if you don't use the result and/or forgot about the delete you don't have any memory leaks.

Answer (score 8):

`return` exits the function prematurely, and is within the body of the `for` loop.

Also, be *very* careful when mixing `unsigned` and `signed` types when using expressions like `i < n`. Do you know off hand what would happen if `n` was 0?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And no, I don't know off hand. I was using unsigned because in my case n should never be negative and I wanted to extend the range in the positive direction. My understanding is quite rudimentary.

Comment: I want to return the values from this into an array. If I can't use `return`, without ending my loop prematurely, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: The equivalent to `s` is modified in the caller. There's no need to explicitly return anything.

Comment: if you want to return an array of values then declare the function to return a pointer to datatype; in your case `double*` as you can see in the answer of @Steranoid.

Comment: If you want to leave `s` as it is, I'd rather see a `std::vector<double>` as the return type. Modern compilers can all obviate the value copy using NRVO.