# C++ How to return dynamically allocated array from function

Tags: c++

I have just started learning C++. I am reading the tutiorials in internet and now I made a dynamically allocated array in function.

```
void array_() {
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    int * Array = new int[size];


    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cin >> Array[i];
}
```

How to return this function to main()

Comment: Returning the pointer? It's no difference between returning a pointer and returning an `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Which happily loses the size information.

Comment: @iksemyonov True, but I'll leave that for another question... :)

Comment: First things first: how would you return an `int` from a function?

Comment: Don't know. Thats why I am asking you. I just want to return array to main() function.

Comment: Even though it's a simple question and it may well be against the rules, I've posted an answer. Just felt it like explaining this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, you can't return a variable of an *array* type (i.e. `int arr[]`) from a function "as is", though you can return a reference or a pointer to an *array*. That is some fairly clumsy syntax though. In the code shown, there is no *array*, rather a pointer to a chunk of dynamically allocated memory. The main problem however is that since the memory is dynamically allocated, when you return a pointer to that memory, you only give the client half the information: the size of the array remains unknown.

Thus, if you really want to stick to traditional arrays allocated dynamically, you can pass the size of the array as a reference parameter ("out-value") to a function like so:

```
int* func(std::size_t& size_out) {
    // int n = ...;
    int* array = new int[n];
    size_out = n;
    return array;
}

int main() {
    int size;
    int* result = func(size);
    delete[] result;
    result = nullptr;
}
```

As you can see, a side-effect of manually allocating memory is that the client takes responsibility of it, and you have to manually delete it *outside of the function where it was allocated*.

But "out-values" are a bad style really, especially in API's. Avoid them whenever you can!

It's of course better to use a proper dynamic array facility such as a `std::vector<T>`, but that seems to not be the point of the exercise.

Reference used: [Return array in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function)

Comment: Why is the first paragraph half about array decay and array pointers when there's none here, and half about saying that pointer+size array passing is somehow related to dynamic allocation, when it's not?

Comment: @Quentin Not a word about decay, since there is none in this example. There is no array. I had decay in the draft but then saw the pointer and removed it.

Comment: You didn't write the word "decay", but it's exactly the reason you can't return an actual array from a function.

Comment: @Quentin Oh do come one I just addressed what the OP said exactly. I don't think I said that returning the said pair is strictly related to dynamic memory allocation, I simply addressed the concerns in this exact post.

Comment: @zett42 True, I actually should point it out as a potential flaw in this approach.

Comment: Well alright, I get what you mean. But still, "since the memory is dynamically allocated" is misleading: the issue would be identical with, for example, a `static` array.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, it's unfortunate effect of I how I worded it, perhaps. Really, was trying to address just what the OP was asking about. Now mine is accepted and better answers are not. :\

Comment: `std::array<T,n>` would be the proper array c++ syntax sugar to directly replace traditional c raw array syntax. `std::vector` is a different sort of data structure [a very close relative]. `std::array` has the same runtime behavior and performance as a raw array. (`std::array` literally gets converted to a raw array during compile.)

Answer (score 10):

Well, it would be wise to return the size as well as the pointer, because otherwise there'll be no way of using the resulting array safely.

So we're looking for a way to return two values from a function. This can be done by taking a reference parameter, through which you assign one of the values:

```
int *array_(int &size) {
    std::cin >> size;

    int *Array = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cin >> Array[i];

    return Array;
}

int main() {
    int size;
    int *arr = array_(size);
    // ...
    delete[] arr; // Don't forget to delete[] what has been new[]'d!
}
```

Or, you could return a `std::pair` containing both values:

```
std::pair<int *, int> array_() {
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;

    int * Array = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cin >> Array[i];

    return {Array, size};
}

int main() {
    auto arr = array_(size);
    // ...
    delete[] arr.second; // Don't forget still!
}
```

But both of these are crazy bad ideas, so you could start right now to write *actual* C++ so it doesn't look like deformed C, using standard containers:

```
std::vector<int> array_() {
    int size = 0;
    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector<int> vec(size);

    for(int &i : vec)
        std::cin >> i;

    return vec;
}

int main() {
    auto arr = array_(size);
    // ...
    // Now you can forget delete: no raw owning pointer, no worries.
}
```

Simple, leak-proof and exception-safe (well, ideally you'd sanitize user input too).

Comment: Is RVO guaranteed to work? `std::vector<T>` is not a Qt-style implicit sharing class.

Comment: @iksemyonov any implementation of reasonable quality will perform NRVO here. Barring that, the vector vill be moved out of the function. In C++17 and beyond, RVO will be guaranteed by the language.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ in most cases we don't need to manually allocate resources using `operator new`.

I suggest to use [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. It has the following advantages over a dynamically allocated plain array:

- It will automatically deallocate the reserved memory when the scope exits (you don't have to call `delete`).
- It has a `size()` method so you always know how many elements are contained in the vector. Compare that with a dynamic plain array where you would have to store the size in another variable.
- You can change the size of the "array" dynamically after construction (using the `resize()` method for instance).

### Example

```
std::vector<int> array_() 
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    // Create a dynamic "array" with the given size.
    std::vector<int> result( size );

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cin >> result[i];

    return result;
}
```

To use that "array" from `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    // Call function array_() and store the result in variable v.
    std::vector<int> v = array_();

    // Print all elements of v using range-based loop.
    for( int x : v )
    {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }

    // Alternatively print all elements using classic loop with index.
    for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the dynamically allocated array returning its pointer:

```
int* ProduceArray() {
    ...
    int* arrayPtr = new int[size];
    ...
    return arrayPtr;
}
```

However, note that in his way you loose the important information of the *size* of the array (which is very important for the code that consumes the array, to avoid buffer overruns).

In modern C++ a better approach is to return a standard library container like `std::vector`, instead of raw pointers.

Note that `std::vector` instances do know their size, and automatically release their memory as well (instead you must explicitly call `delete[]` when you have raw owning pointers).

Comment: "Modern" C++? Is `std::vector` the new hotness now? :p

Comment: "Modern" as in C++11/14/17. In C++98 there was some hesitation when returning containers, and a common practice was reference parameters. With move semantics returning potentially huge movable data is fine.

Comment: But RVO and NRVO are there since the beginning AFAIK, so there's no copy nor move in practice anyway.

Comment: RVO and NRVO were not guaranteed in all cases at least with [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Mmh, RVO issues with MSVC do ring a bell. Fair enough then :)