# How to return an array from a function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm really confused on the theory behind this. Not sure how to return the array from my isAscending function so i can print out in the main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Implement printArray here
void printArray(int array[], int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        cout << array[i] << endl;
};

// Implement isAscending here

int isAscending(int array[], int n){


    for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j <= n; ++j){
            if(array[i] > array[j+1]){
                int temp = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;

            }
        }
    }



    return printArray(array, n);


};

// DO NOT CHANGE MAIN FUNCTION BELOW
int main() {
    int myarray[100];
    cout << "Enter number of integers : ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter " << n << " integers" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       cin >> myarray[i];
    cout << "Contents of array : ";

    printArray(myarray, n);

    cout << "Output of isAscending: " << isAscending(myarray, n) <<    endl;
}
```

Should I use pointers to pass the elements in the array i am stuck.

Comment: You can't `return` arrays in C++.  I'm guessing this is homework because of the comment about not changing `main`, so you probably just want to have `isAscending` `return` a `bool` (in your case, 0 or 1); this would make `isAscending` a predicate function.

Comment: Why are you changing the array in the `isAscending` function

Comment: What exactly is the assignment? Verbatim. Are you supposed to sort the array?

Comment: To return an array use `std::array`.

Comment: I am trying pass array to isascending() function sort it print out the contents in ascending order.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is you don't. When you pass an array to a function, you're actually just passing a pointer to the first element (the array decays to a pointer when you pass it as an argument). This means that if you modify the array in the function, you're modifying the original array and not a copy. Therefore, your `isAscending()` function will bubble sort the array you called it on and it does not need to return anything.

Just a side note, it seems like the assignment simply wants you to check if an array is ascending, instead of sorting it. In that case, `isAscending()` should return a bool.

If you need a function to return an array, you can't just pass a pointer to the first element since the array goes out of scope as soon as the function returns. You could dynamically allocate the array, but that just creates a bunch of new problems. Another way might be to return the pointer to the first element of the array passed to it as an argument like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473448/9254539), but there isn't much point in doing that since the caller already has access to the array.

The best way would be to use something like `std::array` or `std::vector`, which you can return by value just like any other variable. I would also recommend getting a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).

<sub>(I provided this answer besides flagging as a duplicate since I thought the answer of the duplicate question was not complete enough and might mislead someone into trying to return a pointer to a local array)</sub>