# C++ Returning a const unsigned char

Tags: c++

So, I've been struggling with this bit. I have a simple function, that is defined as follows:

```
const unsigned char GetColor(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    const unsigned char color[3] = {0, 1, 0};
    return color;
}
```

Yet, I am not allowed to do this and the compiler returns with the following error:

```
Error: cannot initialize return object of type 'const unsigned char' with an lvalue of type 'const unsigned char [3]'
```

Should I convert the array into a pointer to an array, which I should return? If I do this, don't I risk that it may be deleted after going "out of scope" - aka out of the function?

Any help in understanding this problem will be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: The end goal is to have a function, that can return a color at a pixel location, given an x- and y value. That means that color changes, depending on the value of x- and y. The example above is a simplification.

It should return an const unsigned char array of size 3, with a value in each.

Comment: `std::array<unsigned char, 3>` or `struct Color{ char r; char g; char b; };`

Comment: what is your real goal?
what do you really want to return? a char or a char[]?

Comment: The return type of your function is a const unsigned char but you are returning an array. What you really want to do?

Comment: I want to return a color at a pixel location (x,y). That means that I would like to return a const unsigned char array of the size 3, with the color for the pixel R, G, B in color[0], color[1], color[2]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473438/return-array-in-a-function

Comment: ***That means that I would like to return a const unsigned char array of the size 3***  You can't do exactly the way you want. @MaxVollmer gave two ways that will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to return an array of numbers. You are right that trying to pass some kind of reference to a local variable would create a problem with scope (technically called a dangling pointer / dangling reference), although for different reasons than indicated. (The compiler simply complains about the type disagreement between a single `char` and an array of `char`s.)

C++ gives you several *safe* ways of doing so. For example, you can return an `array` type:

```
#include <array>

std::array<unsigned char, 3> GetColor(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    return {0, 1, 0};
}
```

This makes the "three characters" a single variable of a special type that holds three characters, just like a `struct { unsigned char a, b, c; }`. Or you can make your own type that does something similar.

In the above, you can imagine the "return variable" something invisibly declared by the compiler in a way as if its scope was the statement where you are *calling* the function. The `return` statement writes to this variable, rather than to an array local to this function.

Obviously you'd need to change the calling code such that it expects `std::array<unsigned char, 3>` rather than `unsigned char[3]`, but a) the former version couldn't have worked anyway, so we're speaking of new code rather than trying to change an existing codebase, and b) `std::array`s are usually preferred to C-style arrays anyway in new code and it's worth learning to work with them.

Of course, there's always the *unsafe* way, for example:

```
unsigned char* GetColor(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    unsigned char* ret = new unsigned char[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
    return ret;
}
```

But then you must not forget to `delete[]` the returned pointed once you no longer need it.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice.  Nice explanation

Comment: Thank you very much sir! This was exactly what I was looking for, and I like your explanation!